# Can't get rid of Apache server-status

Tags: apache-2.2, security, fedora

I am trying to deactivate the `/server-status` from an Apache2 running on a Fedora server.

I tried to comment the lines in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and I also tried to make it work only for my IP address, like that:

```
<Location /server-status>
   SetHandler server-status
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 192.168.100.138
   #Allow from 194.106.52.52
   #Allow from localhost
</Location>
```

There is also a Tomcat behind the Apache, and I found that configuration on it, played with that also but got no luck...

*/etc/httpd/vhosts.d/enabled/mysite.conf*

```
#JkUnMount /server-status tomcat6

<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    #Allow from localhost
</Location>
```

I tried to comment and uncomment the JkUnMount line and also the whole location block code.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there any other configuration file that I didn't notice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Find all matches of `/server-status` in web server Apache log files using command:

```
% find /etc/httpd -type f -iname '*.conf' |xargs grep -n "/server-status"
```

**2.** Comment all matched blocks using #
3. Check web server Apache config:

```
% /sbin/service httpd configtest
```

**3.** Restart web server Apache using command:

```
% /sbin/service httpd graceful
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint
There is no need for a restart, a reload is more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Fedora does not include any `Location` blocks for server status, so any that exist were put there by you or another application you installed.

Remove *all* of the `Location` blocks that you set up for this, and then reload Apache.

```
systemctl reload httpd.service
```

Most likely you either forgot to remove one of the `Location` blocks, or you forgot to reload Apache.

Comment: I could not find systemctl so I executed the init script manually.
Nevertheless it worked when I commented both blocks completely, it is weird because I wouldn't mind to have server-status allowed for certain ip's...

Comment: It would help if I hadn't mistyped it. Oops!